# I want to know about these Hadith Prophet Telling Women To Breastfeed Grown Men

Tags: hadith

I want to know about these Hadith Prophet Telling Women To Breastfeed Grown Men: Sahih muslim:1453d https://sunnah.com/abudawud:2061 https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:1943 https://sunnah.com/muslim:1453e https://sunnah.com/malik/30/13 Ṣaḥīḥ muslim:1453a Sahih muslim:1453b https://sunnah.com/muslim:1453c https://sunnah.com/nasai:3323 https://sunnah.com/bulugh/8/193 Sunan nasai:3322

Comment: What do you want to know about them?

Answer (score 1):

These hadith can make reader confused whether it is actual breast feeding or just giving the extracted breast milk. In the hadith it is not clear how this is done. I think it should be giving extracted breast milk because if it is actual breast feeding, then it will involve exposing the breast to a non-mahram which itself is an forbidden act. Of course, after breast feeding he will become mahram but before that he is only a non-mahram and forbidden acts are always to be avoided.

Also, there are different opinion about whether breast feeding an adult will make the person mahram. You can check this link to know more details https://fiqh.islamonline.net/en/breast-feeding-adults-explanation-of-the-hadith-of-salim/

Quote from the above link

> The majority of the Companions of the Prophet (peace and blessings be
> upon him) including all wives of the Prophet (peace and blessings be
> upon him) rejected the opinion of `A’ishah (may Allah be pleased with
> her) and considered the issue as only a particular concession
> concerning the nursing of Salim alone. They do not consider it a
> general ruling that applies to the whole Ummah
>
> Moreover, Sheikh Muhammad Iqbal Nadvi, Imam of Calgary Mosque,
> Alberta, Canada, and former professor at King Saud University, Riyad,
> Saudi Arabia, adds: It is an exceptional situation and exceptional
> solution for the problem mentioned in the hadith. This is the reason
> why our scholars are in unanimity not to apply it in general
> situations. The general rule is that nursing and breast-feeding
> affects the relation only when it is only done before [the one so fed]
> two years old.